# Adding Radio-Button to Standard Wordpress Register Form

Tags: php, wordpress, radio-button, registration

This is my first ever question here, hope I'm doing it all right.
I'm using this [Tutorial](https://www.cssigniter.com/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-the-wordpress-registration-form/) for trying to add a radio-button for setting the user-role to the standard Wordpress register form.

Unfortunately my code does not work properly ($role won't even be filled and I keep getting my own error message). My php knowledge is still at the beginning.

```
...

if($_POST['roleType'] == 'eins') {
        $role = '1';
    } elseif($_POST['roleType'] == 'zwei') {
        $role = '2';
    } elseif($_POST['roleType'] == 'drei') {
        $role = '3';
    } 
    // else { 
    //     $role = 'subscriber';
    // }

    ?>
    <p>
        <label><?php esc_html_e( 'Was wollen Sie inserieren', 'crf' ) ?><br/>
            <input  type="radio"
                    name="roleType"
                    value="eins"
            />1<br>
            <input  type="radio"
                    name="roleType"
                    value="zwei"
            />2<br>
            <input  type="radio"
                    name="roleType"
                    value="drei"
            />3<br>
        </label>
    </p>
    <?php
}

add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'crf_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
function crf_registration_errors( $errors ) {

    if ( empty( $role ) ) {
        $errors->add( 'roleType_empty', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please choose what content you are going to create.', 'crf' ) );
    }

    return $errors;
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'crf_user_register' );
function crf_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $role ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'role', $role );
    }
}
```

I would be greatful if anyone could give me a short hint on what I'm doing wrong, here.

Thanks an cheers,
Johannes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

In the `crf_user_register` function, `$role` is empty because that variable doesn't have a value within the [function's scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

You can either assign a value to `$role`:

```
function crf_user_register( $user_id ) {
    $role = $_POST['roleType'];
    if ( ! empty( $role ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'role', $role );
    }
}
```

Or just use the POST variable:

```
function crf_user_register( $user_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['roleType'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'role', $_POST['roleType'] );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works just fine. In addition I had to correct the field, I'm inserting the data. This did the trick: $user = new WP_User($user_id); $user->set_role($_POST['roleType']);